# Append text to a file using docker heredocs

Tags: docker, docker-build

I'm usually using docker [heredocs](https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/) when I want to create a file on the fly.

```
COPY <<EOF somescript
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    echo "Hello"
EOF
```

This is ok for files that do not exist, but how can I use heredocs and append to an existing file.

Just using `>>` doesn't work

```
COPY <<EOF >> ${USERHOME}/.bashrc
```

The documentation states that you can use `RUN <<EOF` to execute multiple lines:

```
RUN <<EOF
echo "Hello" >> /hello
echo "World!" >> /hello
EOF
```

So I tried a hack and combined docker heredocks with unix heredocs

```
RUN <<EOF
cat <<EOC >> /home/lxo/.bashrc
  echo "TEST"
EOC
EOF
```

But it doesn't work

```
#31 0.388 /bin/bash: line 3: warning: here-document at line 1 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOC')
```

Comment: Can you just `COPY` a completely built file into your image instead?

Comment: No, because I have to append values to a config file that comes from a parent image. The already existing config values must remain intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can `RUN cat`. E.g.

```
RUN cat <<EOF >> ~/.bashrc
   echo "TEST"
EOF
```